# c# pass DB Context object to second function

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to refactor a switch statement so I am not repeating code in each case.

This is a simplified example of the first two cases in my current switch statement. Note the db context objects in case.1 and case.2 `userActions.Action1` and `userActions.Action2`:

```
public void UserClick(int actionNumber, string pageType, string userId, string userEmail)
{
var userActions = _context.RGWActions.Find(userId);
        
switch (actionNumber)
{
     case 1:
          userActions.Action1++;
          userActions.UserTotal++;
     break;
     case 2:
          userActions.Action2++;
          userActions.UserTotal++;
     break;
_context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I want to replace the code in case.1 and case.2 two with something like the below, so that I only have one function call in each:

```
switch (actionNumber)
{
     case 1:
          incrementUserAction(userId, userActions.Action1, "Action1");
     break;
     case 2:
          incrementUserAction(userId, userActions.Action2, "Action2");
     break;
}
```

For my `incrementUserAction` function below, I am passing in the userId and currentValue with no problem. But I can't figure out how to pass in an `actionType` parameter or object or something similar to reference the correct object; `userActions.Action1` or `userActions.Action2` from the cases above.

```
private void incrementUserAction(string userId, int currentValue, string actionType)
{
    var userActions = _context.RGWActions.Find(userId);

    userActions.(actionType) = currentValue++;
    userActions.UserTotal++;
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

In the above example I have tried to just pass a string to represent the column name "Action1" or "Action2". I have also tried variations of `userActions.actionType` and `object actionType` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# objects don't provide easy access to properties by name, so while you could use [reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/reflection) to read and update property values by the specified name, you should generally avoid that for performance and type safety reasons. A better approach here would be to have your `incrementUserAction` method take a [lambda](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/lambda-expressions) that performs the different types of updates:

```
private void incrementUserActions(string userId, Action<RGWActions> update)
{
    var userActions = _context.RGWActions.Find(userId);

    update(userActions);
    userActions.UserTotal++;
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

And the code that calls this function would look like this:

```
switch (actionNumber)
{
     case 1:
          incrementUserAction(userId, userActions => { userActions.Action1++; });
     break;
     case 2:
          incrementUserAction(userId, userActions => { userActions.Action2++; });
     break;
}
```